# DSP low pass filter (IIR) no longer works when changed to a new MCU

Tags: stm32, dsp, digital-filter

I am having troubles understanding why a DSP low pass filter was that working on the M4 is no longer working on an M7.

I recently switched over to a [STM32H753ZI](https://www.st.com/en/microcontrollers-microprocessors/stm32h753zi.html#documentation) from a [STM32L432KC](https://www.st.com/en/microcontrollers-microprocessors/stm32l432kc.html).

In addition to switching from the L4 to H7 I am using the [P2MODI2S2](https://reference.digilentinc.com/reference/pmod/pmodi2s2/reference-manual) with the H7 and not the internal ADC like I was when using the L4.

The only thing that came to mind would be the difference of sampling rates. I was using a 44.410kHz sampling rate on the L4 and now I am using a 96kHz sampling rate on the H7 using the PMODI2S2. So I re-did the discrete function and put in the new IIR coefficients and no cigar.

Using the H7 with the PMODI2S2 as a passthrough:

[image]

CODE:

```
#define ARM_MATH_CM7

#include "main.h"

#include "arm_math.h"


void init_Clock(void);
void init_I2S(void);
void init_Debugging(void);
void init_Interrupt(void);
void init_SpeedTest(void);

uint32_t RxBuff[4];
uint32_t TxBuff[4];
uint8_t TC_Callback = 0;
uint8_t HC_Callback = 0;

char uartBuff[8];

float iir_coeffs[5] = {0.00102, 0.002041, 0.00102, 1.908, -0.9116}; //B0, B1, B2, A1, A2
float iir_mono_state[4];

float Rx_Buff_f[8];
float Rx_Buff_f_out[8];


arm_biquad_casd_df1_inst_f32 monoChannel;


void DMA1_Stream0_IRQHandler(void) {

    if (((DMA1 -> LISR) & (DMA_LISR_TCIF0)) != 0){
        DMA1 -> LIFCR |= DMA_LIFCR_CTCIF0;
        TC_Callback = 1;
    }

    else if (((DMA1 -> LISR) & (DMA_LISR_HTIF0)) != 0){
         DMA1 -> LIFCR |= DMA_LIFCR_CHTIF0;
         HC_Callback = 1;

    }
}

int main(void) {

    init_Clock();
    init_I2S();
    //init_Debugging();
    init_Interrupt();
    //init_SpeedTest();
    arm_biquad_cascade_df1_init_f32(&monoChannel, 1, iir_coeffs, iir_mono_state);

  while (1)
  {

      if (HC_Callback == 1){

         // GPIOA->BSRR |= GPIO_BSRR_BS3_HIGH;

         

          for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
                TxBuff[i] = RxBuff[i];
            }

          HC_Callback = 0;

      } else  if (TC_Callback == 1){


        //  GPIOA->BSRR |= GPIO_BSRR_BR3_LOW;



                  for (int i = 2; i < 4; i++){
                        TxBuff[i] =  RxBuff[i];
                    }



          TC_Callback = 0;

      }



  }

}
```

H7 with PMODI2S2 with IIR coefficients using 96kHz sampling rate:

[image]

Code:

```
#define ARM_MATH_CM7

#include "main.h"

#include "arm_math.h"


void init_Clock(void);
void init_I2S(void);
void init_Debugging(void);
void init_Interrupt(void);
void init_SpeedTest(void);

uint32_t RxBuff[4];
uint32_t TxBuff[4];
uint8_t TC_Callback = 0;
uint8_t HC_Callback = 0;

char uartBuff[8];

float iir_coeffs[5] = {0.00102, 0.002041, 0.00102, 1.908, -0.9116}; //B0, B1, B2, A1, A2
float iir_mono_state[4];

float Rx_Buff_f[8];
float Rx_Buff_f_out[8];


arm_biquad_casd_df1_inst_f32 monoChannel;


void DMA1_Stream0_IRQHandler(void) {

    if (((DMA1 -> LISR) & (DMA_LISR_TCIF0)) != 0){
        DMA1 -> LIFCR |= DMA_LIFCR_CTCIF0;
        TC_Callback = 1;
    }

    else if (((DMA1 -> LISR) & (DMA_LISR_HTIF0)) != 0){
         DMA1 -> LIFCR |= DMA_LIFCR_CHTIF0;
         HC_Callback = 1;

    }
}

int main(void) {

    init_Clock();
    init_I2S();
    //init_Debugging();
    init_Interrupt();
    //init_SpeedTest();
    arm_biquad_cascade_df1_init_f32(&monoChannel, 1, iir_coeffs, iir_mono_state);

  while (1)
  {

      if (HC_Callback == 1){

         // GPIOA->BSRR |= GPIO_BSRR_BS3_HIGH;

          for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
              Rx_Buff_f[i] = (float)RxBuff[i];
          }

          arm_biquad_cascade_df1_f32(&monoChannel, Rx_Buff_f, Rx_Buff_f_out, 2);

          for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
                TxBuff[i] = (uint32_t)Rx_Buff_f_out[i];
            }

          HC_Callback = 0;

      } else  if (TC_Callback == 1){


        //  GPIOA->BSRR |= GPIO_BSRR_BR3_LOW;


          for (int i = 2; i < 4; i++){
               Rx_Buff_f[i] = (float)RxBuff[i];
            }

                  arm_biquad_cascade_df1_f32(&monoChannel, &Rx_Buff_f[2], &Rx_Buff_f_out[2], 2);

                  for (int i = 2; i < 4; i++){
                        TxBuff[i] =  (uint32_t)Rx_Buff_f_out[i];
                    }



          TC_Callback = 0;

      }



  }

}
```

So I thought to myself, since I am using a I2S protocol and since its stereo I tried using a sampling rate of 192kHz just to see what happens:

[image]

CODE:

```
#define ARM_MATH_CM7

#include "main.h"

#include "arm_math.h"


void init_Clock(void);
void init_I2S(void);
void init_Debugging(void);
void init_Interrupt(void);
void init_SpeedTest(void);

uint32_t RxBuff[4];
uint32_t TxBuff[4];
uint8_t TC_Callback = 0;
uint8_t HC_Callback = 0;

char uartBuff[8];

float iir_coeffs[5] = {0.0002507, 0.0005013, 0.0002507, 1.955, -0.9557}; //B0, B1, B2, A1, A2
float iir_mono_state[4];

float Rx_Buff_f[8];
float Rx_Buff_f_out[8];


arm_biquad_casd_df1_inst_f32 monoChannel;


void DMA1_Stream0_IRQHandler(void) {

    if (((DMA1 -> LISR) & (DMA_LISR_TCIF0)) != 0){
        DMA1 -> LIFCR |= DMA_LIFCR_CTCIF0;
        TC_Callback = 1;
    }

    else if (((DMA1 -> LISR) & (DMA_LISR_HTIF0)) != 0){
         DMA1 -> LIFCR |= DMA_LIFCR_CHTIF0;
         HC_Callback = 1;

    }
}

int main(void) {

    init_Clock();
    init_I2S();
    //init_Debugging();
    init_Interrupt();
    //init_SpeedTest();
    arm_biquad_cascade_df1_init_f32(&monoChannel, 1, iir_coeffs, iir_mono_state);

  while (1)
  {

      if (HC_Callback == 1){

         // GPIOA->BSRR |= GPIO_BSRR_BS3_HIGH;

          for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
              Rx_Buff_f[i] = (float)RxBuff[i];
          }

          arm_biquad_cascade_df1_f32(&monoChannel, Rx_Buff_f, Rx_Buff_f_out, 2);

          for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
                TxBuff[i] = (uint32_t)Rx_Buff_f_out[i];
            }

          HC_Callback = 0;

      } else  if (TC_Callback == 1){


        //  GPIOA->BSRR |= GPIO_BSRR_BR3_LOW;


          for (int i = 2; i < 4; i++){
               Rx_Buff_f[i] = (float)RxBuff[i];
            }

                  arm_biquad_cascade_df1_f32(&monoChannel, &Rx_Buff_f[2], &Rx_Buff_f_out[2], 2);

                  for (int i = 2; i < 4; i++){
                        TxBuff[i] =  (uint32_t)Rx_Buff_f_out[i];
                    }



          TC_Callback = 0;

      }



  }

}
```

Any ideas? I am not sure if its the M7 or the peripheral in question. This was working on an L4, no problem.

UPDATE 1:
I recorded the variables in debugger mode to see what is happening. I took three pictures. The first iteration is index 0-2 and the second iteration from 2-4 and the third picture is many iterations afterwards.

[image]

[image]

[image]

What I noticed is that RxBuffer and RxBuffer_f are out of sync. I also noticed that many iterations later the RxBuffer_f_out just becomes an int like data type and no longer contain any sort of decimals.

UPDATE 2:

I also notice that I am using a I2S device that shoots out stereo audio, am I maybe not adding the coefficients properly to the buffers. What I mean by this do I need to adjust the buffers when they come in, like bit shift them or anything along those lines? The only thing I know about that PMODI2S2 is that I believe it shoots out 24 bits in a 32 data frame, so I am assuming its padded with zeroes and why not.

UPDATE 3:

Was playing around with just multiplying the RxBuffer before putting in the TxBuffer and what it did was increase the PK - PK of the signal, however increasing it more caused this:

Multiplying the RxBuffer by 2^0 (Passthrough)

[image]

Multiplying the RxBuffer by 2^1

[image]

Multiplying the RxBuffer by 2^2

[image]

The last picture looks like the problem I am having, is this maybe an overflow issue?

UPDATE 4:

Talking to a concerned citizen he mentioned the I2S protocol is a 2's complement data encoded. I know what 2's complement is, however I am not sure if the TxBuff or the Rxbuff needs to be complemented. Anyhow I changed both data type of the TxBuff and the Rxbuff to int32_t datatypes and the problem still insist.

UPDATE 5: Tried using the 2's complement or simply just casting it as an int32_t. No luck.

CODE:

```
#define ARM_MATH_CM7

#include "main.h"

#include "arm_math.h"


void init_Clock(void);
void init_I2S(void);
void init_Debugging(void);
void init_Interrupt(void);
void init_SpeedTest(void);

uint32_t RxBuff[4];
uint32_t TxBuff[4];
uint8_t TC_Callback = 0;
uint8_t HC_Callback = 0;

char uartBuff[8];

float iir_coeffs[5] = {0.00102, 0.002041, 0.00102, 1.908, -0.9116}; //B0, B1, B2, A1, A2
float iir_mono_state[4];

float Rx_Buff_f[4];
float Rx_Buff_f_out[4];


arm_biquad_casd_df1_inst_f32 monoChannel;


void DMA1_Stream0_IRQHandler(void) {

    if (((DMA1 -> LISR) & (DMA_LISR_TCIF0)) != 0){
        DMA1 -> LIFCR |= DMA_LIFCR_CTCIF0;
        TC_Callback = 1;
    }

    else if (((DMA1 -> LISR) & (DMA_LISR_HTIF0)) != 0){
         DMA1 -> LIFCR |= DMA_LIFCR_CHTIF0;
         HC_Callback = 1;

    }
}

int main(void) {

    init_Clock();
    init_I2S();
    //init_Debugging();
    init_Interrupt();
    //init_SpeedTest();
    arm_biquad_cascade_df1_init_f32(&monoChannel, 1, iir_coeffs, iir_mono_state);

  while (1)
  {

      if (HC_Callback == 1){

         // GPIOA->BSRR |= GPIO_BSRR_BS3_HIGH;

          for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
              Rx_Buff_f[i] = (float)((int32_t)RxBuff[i]);
          }

          arm_biquad_cascade_df1_f32(&monoChannel, Rx_Buff_f, Rx_Buff_f_out, 2);

          for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
                TxBuff[i] = (int32_t)Rx_Buff_f_out;
            }

          HC_Callback = 0;

      } else  if (TC_Callback == 1){


        //  GPIOA->BSRR |= GPIO_BSRR_BR3_LOW;


          for (int i = 2; i < 4; i++){
               Rx_Buff_f[i] = (float)((int32_t)RxBuff[i]);
            }

                  arm_biquad_cascade_df1_f32(&monoChannel, &Rx_Buff_f[2], &Rx_Buff_f_out[2], 2);

                  for (int i = 2; i < 4; i++){
                        TxBuff[i] =  (int32_t)Rx_Buff_f_out;
                    }



          TC_Callback = 0;

      }



  }

}
```

UPDATE 6:

Changed code according to a concerned citizen comments

CODE:

```
#define ARM_MATH_CM7

#include "main.h"

#include "arm_math.h"


void init_Clock(void);
void init_I2S(void);
void init_Debugging(void);
void init_Interrupt(void);
void init_SpeedTest(void);

int32_t RxBuff[4];
int32_t TxBuff[4];
uint8_t TC_Callback = 0;
uint8_t HC_Callback = 0;

char uartBuff[8];
 float32_t iir_coeffs[5] = {0.00102, 0.002041, 0.00102, 1.908, -0.9116}; //B0, B1, B2, A1, A2
float32_t iir_mono_state[4];

float32_t Rx_Buff_f[4];
float32_t Rx_Buff_f_out[4];


arm_biquad_casd_df1_inst_f32 monoChannel;


void DMA1_Stream0_IRQHandler(void) {

    if (((DMA1 -> LISR) & (DMA_LISR_TCIF0)) != 0){
        DMA1 -> LIFCR |= DMA_LIFCR_CTCIF0;
        TC_Callback = 1;
    }

    else if (((DMA1 -> LISR) & (DMA_LISR_HTIF0)) != 0){
         DMA1 -> LIFCR |= DMA_LIFCR_CHTIF0;
         HC_Callback = 1;

    }
}

int main(void) {

    init_Clock();
    init_I2S();
    //init_Debugging();
    init_Interrupt();
    //init_SpeedTest();
    arm_biquad_cascade_df1_init_f32(&monoChannel, 1, iir_coeffs, iir_mono_state);

  while (1)
  {

      if (HC_Callback == 1){

         // GPIOA->BSRR |= GPIO_BSRR_BS3_HIGH;

          for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
              Rx_Buff_f[i] = (float32_t)RxBuff[i];
          }

          arm_biquad_cascade_df1_f32(&monoChannel, Rx_Buff_f, Rx_Buff_f_out, 2);

          for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
                TxBuff[i] = Rx_Buff_f_out[i];
            }

          HC_Callback = 0;

      } else  if (TC_Callback == 1){


        //  GPIOA->BSRR |= GPIO_BSRR_BR3_LOW;


          for (int i = 2; i < 4; i++){
               Rx_Buff_f[i] = (float32_t)RxBuff[i];
            }

                  arm_biquad_cascade_df1_f32(&monoChannel, &Rx_Buff_f[2], &Rx_Buff_f_out[2], 2);

                  for (int i = 2; i < 4; i++){
                        TxBuff[i] =  Rx_Buff_f_out[i];
                    }



          TC_Callback = 0;

      }



  }

}
```

Comment: That looks like an offset, signedness or I2S bit position error.  Try first with what should be a straight passthrough with no processing.

Comment: Isnt that what my first picture is? Its just a pass through no processing

Comment: Then try different patterns and see if you can figure out where it goes bad.  Particularly, try to separate the algorithm from the output.  You might build a quick and dirty 8-sample sine synthesizer with a multiplicate volume control and feed that through the output verifying you have the numeric range you think you do.

Comment: is there a chance it could be caused not taking in the data properly if its stereo and being sent as a 24bit anything along those lines, do I need to bit shift anythign

Comment: @ChrisStratton Alright, I found out where it broke besides using the algorithm

Comment: @Leoc That looks like it. You're working with `uint32_t`, so the high amplification causes the values to wrap. Add this as an answer, it's useful for the future, when people will search for similar problems, when they will see this question with an answer. If you think that solves your problems, accept your own answer.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen ill look further into it, but I guess the next step is how big is the buffer inside the PMODI2S2 when accepting the data? So far I guess the datatype for the PMODI2S2 Receiving side is less than uint32_t for sure

Comment: @Leoc I could be wrong, but it looks like you're not modifying the buffer, but the amplification. Changing the buffer size should not have any impact on the amplitude.

Comment: All I did was Rxbuffer[i] << 1 , etc. There's a chance its an overflow. When I change the buffer to let say uint16_t everything becomes whack, I can update main post if you like

Comment: @Leoc I'll take your word for it, but I also don't see the connection, so I'll leave it to others.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen Fair enough, Yeah I have no idea what's going on. I suspected it was the sampling rate when I created the difference equation, but nope. Only thing I can think of is the size of the buffers with the overflow, or the DSP library is off with the H7(M7)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115082/discussion-between-a-concerned-citizen-and-leoc).

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen the 2's complement info was the trick to get the signal back to normal however the digital filter isnt working

Comment: Disregard what I said, I send the wrong variable to the TxBuffer

Comment: Updated the Post

Comment: Got it working holy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution:

So, I got it working I am not sure if it was due to poorly documentation of I2S or me not understanding the left/ right aligness of a bit, but after reading this on a forum from one the of users, it stated this

**"The one you show is Left-justified or as TI calls it "Standard format""**

I saw the standard format from here the [ADC C5343 datasheet](https://statics.cirrus.com/pubs/proDatasheet/CS5343-44_F5.pdf) on Pg. 14 in the Serial Audio Interface timing diagram.

Then I tried in the SPI_I2SCFGR register and changed the DATFMT bit to 0x01 for Left aligned and boom everything worked. The filter is working and the wave looks perfect.

The only question left is why it left the voltage on my output sine wave so small ~340mV Pk-PK

Comment: So it was the darn signed-ness, after all. This was long battle, I'm glad it's over. +1 from me, because you earned it. You can also accept your own answer. Future searches for this kind of problem will reveal a question with an accepted answer.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen  We did it mate! Holy feel like celebrating hahaha. I dont get it how the heck would I know its Left aligned if I didnt get lucky with a google search

Comment: What frequency is the signal? Maybe it falls in the stopband?

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen The signal input is currently at 620Hz, the stopband is around 2kHz. Could it be the lose of data from going from float -> int32_t?
Because with the passthrough it was around 600mV so I lost 6dB worth of gain somewhere

Comment: Be sure to use the correct sampling, what sampling frequency did you calculate your coefficients for?

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen The sampling rate I used to create my coefficients were for 96kHz

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115120/discussion-between-a-concerned-citizen-and-leoc).